# SVG to JSON on server side?

Tags: php, json, svg, server-side

Our web application is storing SVG files on server, we want to get JSON outputs from SVG files on server side.
I've looked into [PETESAIA's SVG to JSON](http://petesaia.com/2011/11/svg-to-json/)  php program.
But the output i am getting is null or an empty array.

```
<?php
require_once “PeachSVG.php”;
$filename = “filename-2012-03-06.svg”;
$json = PeachSVG::convert($filename, $to_json = true);
//$json = convert($filename, $to_json = true);   //also used this one
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
?>
```

This php code, PeachSVG.php and the svg file are in the same directory.

Can anyone suggest where i am wrong going with this?

Or any alternative of SVG to JSON on server side

**EDIT :** In response to @halfer and his query about why we need server side validation of SVG (converted to JSON).
We have a cleint-side SVG(RaphaelJs) web app in which a user can perform certain actions, output is sent to and saved on our server and posted on a website. We want to make sure that output file is validated before posted on the website. For this we need to have server side validation to make sure that the user does not abuse the rules set in the application.

Raphael.serialize can not be used because it converts SVG to JSON on the client side which may be abused by the user. So we sending the SVG document as a string to server side.

Comment: What's your use case? Are you holding SVG docs on the server and wish to render them on the browser? If so, can they not be rendered directly via AJAX using Raphael or something?

Comment: Have you turned on notices and all error reporting for your code above, btw? Maybe there is a buglet that needs tracking down?

Comment: Yes our SVG docs are on the server but we don't need to render it back on the browser. We need to use JSON of SVG for some validation purpose.

Comment: Could you not use XMLReader, so you can validate against the DTD? Or load into SimpleXML and use XPath checks? If you are able to explain why you want to validate using JSON, and what your validations are, someone may have a better suggestion for you.

Comment: i updated the question, described use case

Comment: Cool. OK, could you not use `Raphael.serialize()` and then decode the JSON on the server and run checks on it that way?

Comment: We thought of that, but Raphael.serialize does not help us in some ways. e.g, <clipPaths..> and <g> are not supported by Raphael, so not included in Raphael.serialize. We using simple JS to append clipPath and and g in the same SVG document.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install Node.js on your server you might be able to use fabric.js to parse the SVG then export the objects as JSON.

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js

http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/svg_rendering/

Comment: Unfortunately we can't Install Node.js. Please refer us any other solution if you can, php based solution would be best

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in require_once() function. The path to the php file should be in parentheses, like this:

```
require_once("PeachSVG.php");
```

And for strings you seem to use not good double quotes. You probably copied them from somewhere. Because these are left double quotation mark "“" (U+201C) and right double quotation mark "”" (U+201D). In code it should look not like this:

```
“some your string”
```

but like this:

```
"some your string"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Script ran very fine on my localhost server but i have to remove the quotation marks you had and replace it with one from my notepad++ which looks like string quotes to me. hope this helps if had not found a solution yet